# Presto convert timestamp to epoch

Tags: presto

In redshift, I can do something like this

`date_part(epoch, '2019-03-07 10:17:03.000000')` and it would return `1551953823`. How do I do this in Presto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use [`to_unixtime`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#to_unixtime):

```
presto> select to_unixtime(timestamp '2019-03-07 10:17:03');
     _col0
---------------
 1.551953823E9
(1 row)
```

or use [`date_diff`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_diff) to subtract the timestamp from the epoch timestamp:

```
presto> select date_diff('second', timestamp '1970-01-01', timestamp '2019-03-07 10:17:03');
   _col0
------------
 1551953823
(1 row)
```

Note that `to_unixtime` returns a double representing the number of seconds plus milliseconds as a fractional part. If you want just the seconds, you can cast the result to `BIGINT`:

```
presto> select cast(to_unixtime(timestamp '2019-03-07 10:17:03') as bigint);
   _col0
------------
 1551953823
(1 row)
```

Comment: ooh thank you, the docs was a bit confusing for me. It looks like i was incorrectly using it as `select to_unixtime('2019-03-07 10:17:03')` and not `select to_unixtime(timestamp '2019-03-07 10:17:03')`